# Argument of type 'PTOData[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PTOData'

Tags: angular

In my angular project, I'm getting the error stated in the title and the explanation for it is `"Property 'ID' is missing in type 'PTOData[]'."`But, whenever I add `.ID` on the end of it, it then says `"Property 'ID' does not exist on type 'PTOData[]'."` and it definitely does. Did I do something wrong somewhere?

Here's my .ts file:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

import { PTOData } from './pto-data';
import { PTODataService } from './pto-data.service';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: '[pto-row-edit]',
    templateUrl: `./row-edit.component.html`,
    styleUrls: ['./row-edit.component.css']
})

export class RowEditComponent {
    @Input() pto: PTOData[];

    constructor(
        private ptodataservice: PTODataService,
        private location: Location) { }

    saveRow(): void {
        this.ptodataservice.update(this.pto.ID)
    }
}
```

and here's my .html file:

```html
<td><input class='form-control' type="date" id="ptoDate" [ngModel]="pto.date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'" (ngModelChange)="pto.date=$event" name="ptoDate" /></td>
<td>
  <select class="form-control" id="ptoFullHalf" [(ngModel)]="pto.fullhalf" name="ptoFullHalf">
    <option value="full">Full</option>
    <option value="AM">AM</option>
    <option value="PM">PM</option>
    <option value="(full)">(Full)</option>
    <option value="(half)">(Half)</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <select class="form-control" id="ptoHours" [(ngModel)]="pto.hours" name="ptoHours">
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="-4">-4</option>
    <option value="-8">-8</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td>
  <select class="form-control" id="ptoScheduled" [(ngModel)]="pto.scheduled" name="ptoScheduled">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="advanced">Advanced</option>
    <option value="scheduled">Scheduled</option>
    <option value="unscheduled">Unscheduled</option>
  </select>
</td>
<td><input class='form-control' type="text" id="ptoNotes" [(ngModel)]="pto.notes" name="ptoNotes" /></td>
<td>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="ptoinPR" [(ngModel)]="pto.inPR" name="ptoinPR" />
</td>
<td>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="float:right;"><i class="fa fa-ban" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <button class="btn btn-default btn-primary" style="float:right;" (click)="saveRow()"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</td>
```

Also here's my update function

```js
    update(pto: PTOData): Promise<PTOData> {
        return this.http
            .put(this.ptoDateUrl, JSON.stringify(pto), { headers: this.headers })
            .toPromise()
            .then(() => pto)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a **`object`** not **`array`**,

```
export class RowEditComponent {
    @Input() pto: PTOData;
```

or you just need to pass the id of particular object, pass the index

```
saveRow(): void {
    this.ptodataservice.update(this.pto[0].ID)
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your service, you need to pass the complete object not an ID,

Try passing this.pto

```
saveRow(): void {
    this.ptodataservice.update(this.pto)
}
```

Comment: whenever I do either of those I'm getting an error that says `"Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PTOData'."`

Comment: that's what I had at first but it gives me an error saying `"Property 'ID' is missing in type 'PTOData[]'."`

Comment: does your PTOData has ID inside it

Comment: yeah, when I peek definition, it has it there

Comment: @rarc did you try to change the input as i mentioned?